# Reasource Dictionary's and Storyboards

Tags: wpf, storyboard

Having an issue moving a storybord to a resource dictionary for use across my enitre application.

basically want to use the same story board on multiple user control's.

Resource Dicitionary

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever" x:Key="AnimateWidth">
<DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" From="1" To="250" Duration="0:0:2" BeginTime="0:0:0" FillBehavior="Stop" />
</Storyboard>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

UserControl

```
<UserControl x:Class="Toolset.WMIControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:View="clr-namespace:Toolset"
             Name="WmiControl_UserControl"
             Loaded="UserControl_Loaded"

             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             >
<UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Animations">
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="AnimationStyles.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>


    </UserControl.Resources>

 <DockPanel Name="DockPanel1" Style="{StaticResource Animations}">
            <DockPanel.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">

                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{Binding AnimateWidth, Source={StaticResource Animations}}"/>
            </EventTrigger>
        </DockPanel.Triggers>
    </DockPanel>
```

Not really sure where i have gone wrong here. Any help would be appreciated.
Getting error "Must have a Storyboard object referenced before this trigger action can execute.

Comment: In `BeginStoryboard` try use `StaticResource` like this: `<BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource AnimateWidth}" />`. In `ResourceDictionary` key is not necessary, `x:Key="Animations"` must be removed.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="AnimationStyles.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>

<DockPanel Name="DockPanel1">
    <DockPanel.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource AnimateWidth}"/>
        </EventTrigger>
    </DockPanel.Triggers>
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: Cannot find resource named 'AnimateWidth'. Resource names are case sensitive Also I have to name the Resource Dictionary because it says that each resource dictionary must have a key

Comment: `DockPanel` is in the `UserControl` right? so the Resources of `UserControl` also used by the `DockPanel`..

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question..

This is how you use animations from a ResourceDictionary that is in another file.
Without using C#, since your not styling the view keep it in the view

```
 <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Animations">
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="AnimationStyles.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
  </ResourceDictionary>

       <DockPanel x:Name="Simple_Mode" DockPanel.Dock="Top" 
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
                       Resources="{StaticResource Animations}" 
                       >
                <DockPanel.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource AnimateWidth}"/>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </DockPanel.Triggers>
        </DockPanel>
```